# Page.isValid Problem in conditional validation

Tags: c#, javascript, validation

i have a series of text box with required field validator and a textarea with required field validator a checkbox and a button on click of which i am checking for validation all have the same validation group
on checking the checkbox i am disabling the textboxes as well as their validations and enabling the validation for text area but if checkbox is not checked all controls are enabled but the validation for textarea is disabled the problem is that if checkbox is not checked and i am inserting values to all textboxes but not to the text area and hitting the save button  on code behind i am checking for Page.isValid before inserting the values to Database but this Page.isValid is always returning false because of text area required field validator  even if it is disabled.

the javascript code for this is

```
 // Function for enabling/disabling validation
function enableValidation(element, enable)
{
    $.each(Page_Validators, function()
    {
        if (this.controltovalidate == element.id)
        {
            ValidatorEnable(this, enable);
        }
    });
}

// Funcion Called on the click event of checkbox in 
// Provide Project Feedback popup in TestCATFeedback page.
function disableOtherElements(e)
{
    if (e.checked)
    {
        $('.disableIt').each(function()
        {
            enableValidation(this, false);
        }).attr('disabled', true).css('opacity', 0.3);
        $('.noteBox').each(function()
        {
            enableValidation(this, true);
        });

        $('.noteBox').focus();
    } 
    else
    {
        $('.disableIt').each(function()
        {
            enableValidation(this, true);
        }).removeAttr('disabled').css('opacity', 1);
        $('.noteBox').each(function()
        {
            enableValidation(this, false);
        });
    }
}
```

here disableIt is the class assigned to each of the textbox control and notebox is the class assigned to textarea

how to fix this issue that if a validation control is disabled then don't check that for page validation and return true Page.isValid check

Answer (score 0):

Disable clientside validation for the controls and on the pageload enable/disable validation of the controls as per the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I was able to find for this problem was to create a "bPageIsValidated" variable.  This variable defaults to "false".  Then, in each server side validator, it is set to true.  This lets you know if validation has occurred yet or not.  It's a very simple and straightforward technique so I think it should take care of this problem pretty handily.